# Child of the scoped flow was cancelled

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I randomly get en Error Child of the scoped flow was cancelled, place where it's appering in a ViewModel every time I type in query in to get data in Flow fetchGalleryItem:

```
try {
                    fetchGalleryItems(storedQuery).cachedIn(viewModelScope).collect { fetchedItems ->
                        _uiState.update { oldState ->
                            oldState.copy(
                                images = fetchedItems,
                                query = storedQuery
                            )
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch  items", ex)
                }
```

Here is example of a ViewModel:

```
class PhotoGalleryViewModel:ViewModel() {
    private val photoRepository = PhotoRepository()
    private val preferencesRepository = PreferencesRepository.get()
    private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<PhotoGalleryUiState> = MutableStateFlow(PhotoGalleryUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<PhotoGalleryUiState>
        get() = _uiState.asStateFlow()



    init {
        viewModelScope.launch() {
            preferencesRepository.storedQuery.collectLatest { storedQuery ->
                try {
                    fetchGalleryItems(storedQuery).cachedIn(viewModelScope).collect { fetchedItems ->
                        _uiState.update { oldState ->
                            oldState.copy(
                                images = fetchedItems,
                                query = storedQuery
                            )
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch  items", ex)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    fun setQuery(query: String) {
           viewModelScope.launch {
               preferencesRepository.setStoredQuery(query)
           }
    }

    private fun fetchGalleryItems(query: String): Flow<PagingData<GalleryItem>> {
        return if (query.isEmpty()){
            photoRepository.fetchPhotos()
        } else{
            photoRepository.searchPhotos(query)
        }

    }
}
```

Here is Fragment onViewCreated code if it will be any helpfull

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.photoGrid.adapter = adapter
        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(object: MenuProvider{
            override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_photo_gallery, menu)
            }

            override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return when (menuItem.itemId){
                    R.id.menu_item_search -> {
                        searchView = menuItem.actionView as? SearchView
                        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                                photoGalleryViewModel.setQuery(query ?: "")
                                return true
                            }
                            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                                return false
                            }
                        })
                        true
                    }
                    R.id.menu_item_clear -> {
                        photoGalleryViewModel.setQuery("")
                        true
                    } else -> false
                }
            }
        },viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                photoGalleryViewModel.uiState.collectLatest{
                    adapter.submitData(it.images)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can you guys help me, what is wrond with collect() lambdas.

Is there anything wrong with provided synthax? I searched for an answer in https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1433
But issue is closed already and as I see the problem was in combine() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using try catch blocks with suspending functions it's recommended to always rethrow [`CancellationException`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.cancellation/-cancellation-exception/)s and not threat them as an error:

```
 catch (ce: CancellationException) {
    throw ce
 } catch (ex: Exception) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch  items", ex)
 }
```

In your case you catch `CancellationException`s that are used to handle internal jobs of `collectLatest` (and when viewmodel scope is shut down).